# net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) Azure Functions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, azure-functions, jcrop

I am serving an HTML file using Azure Functions. However, I am unable to link to css files and reference js scripts within the directory, resulting in an error, i.e. `HttpTrigger1:19 GET http://localhost:7071/api/js/jquery.min.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)`

The path to the js and css files seem to be correct. How to prevent this error from occurring? The directory as well as the index.html and index.js can be found in the following.

Directory

```
HttpTrigger1
│   function.json
│   image.jpg
│   index.html
│   index.js
│   sample.dat
|
├───css
│       bootstrap.min.css
│       jquery.Jcrop.min.css
│
└───js
        bootstrap.min.js
        form-image-crop.js
        jquery.color.js
        jquery.Jcrop.min.js
        jquery.min.js
```

index.js

```
var fs = require('fs');


module.exports = function (context, req) {
    var filepath = __dirname + '/index.html'
    fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf8', function (err, content) {
        if (err) {
            context.log.error(err);
            context.done(err);
        }
        //context.log(result.name);
        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            headers: 
                {
                    'Content-Type': 'text/html'
                },
            body: content
        };
        context.done();
    });
}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>hello world</title>
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/jcrop/dist/jcrop.css"> -->
        <link href="./css/jquery.Jcrop.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="./css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello world!</h1>
        <div id="cordCon">
            X: <input name="x"><br />
            Y: <input name="y"><br />
            W: <input name="w"><br />
            H: <input name="h">
        </div>
        <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-EMgI2OzK2E0/T2xktULgfMI/AAAAAAAAAQE/WSQU5IR_mdQ/s443/bipolar-nature-ipad-wallpapers.jpg" id="target">
        
        <script src="./js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="./js/jquery.Jcrop.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <!-- <script src="https://unpkg.com/jcrop"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
       
            $.Jcrop('#target', {
                /*setSelect: [400, 200, 50, 50], */
                aspectRatio: 16 / 8,
                onSelect: showCords, 
                onChange: showCords
            }/*, function(){
                jcrop_api = this;
            }*/);
        });//end document ready fn
        function showCords(c){
            console.log(c);
            $('input[name="x"]').val(c.x);
            $('input[name="y"]').val(c.y);
            $('input[name="w"]').val(c.w);
            $('input[name="h"]').val(c.h);
        }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is static file serving configured?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the `js` folder is under `HttpTrigger1`, so when request `http://localhost:7071/api/js/jquery.min.js`, it shows 404.

You should use `http://localhost:7071/api/HttpTrigger1/js/jquery.min.js` or you can also change the lever of the folder `js`(move it to same level with `HttpTrigger1`).